# Optimal bed and hot end temperature for bed adhesion with PLA on a Bambu P1P

Tags: adhesion

Using Bambu matte black filament, a Bambu textured PEI bed, and a Bambu P1P printer without an enclosure, what is the optimum bed and hot end temperature for maximum adhesion on a tall thin print with a low level of contact (corner piece for one of the official enclosure).

Please limit any answers to temperature, other issues such as speed, the use of contact shapes, or bed adhesion products are out of scope for this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the material specifications, the mate has a Heat Deflection Temperature of 58 °C which can be assumed as the glass transition temperature. So you can bring your bed temperature as close to this as you dare for better adhesion. (you might even be able to go a bit over it if your part is not sagging)

But this will have only a limited effect. Not wanting to look at efficient solutions like a brim and 3Dlac to gain adhesion area might not allow you to solve the problem.

A nice trick if you are scared not to be able to remove the brim cleanly is to do a skirt with a 0.2 or 0.3 mm gap this will allow it to hold sufficiently to help adhesion but still be easy to remove.

Comment: I've been told to limit the scope of my questions, so I'm tackling brims and skirts seperatly.